# Content in POST request is null

Tags: http-post, asp.net-web-api2

I am using the following code as a controller action corresponding to a POST request.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(value, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")
            };
            return response;
        }
```

I am generating the request using RESTClient plugin for Firefox. However, each time the value turns out null. Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

The captured response from Fiddler is as follows:

```
POST http://localhost/api/default/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: null
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 5
Cookie: ai_user=5EE27B20-4A54-4651-820A-9D9654C2D891|2015-07-28T13:00:05.013Z
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

qwert
```

Update 1:
As per comments, I tried the "value="format but it does not help either.

```
POST http://localhost/api/default/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: null
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 11
Cookie: ai_user=5EE27B20-4A54-4651-820A-9D9654C2D891|2015-07-28T13:00:05.013Z
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

value=qwert
```

The above snippet is the fiddler capture of the new request. Also tried JSON request; but that does not work either.

```
POST http://localhost/api/default/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: null
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 17
Cookie: ai_user=5EE27B20-4A54-4651-820A-9D9654C2D891|2015-07-28T13:00:05.013Z
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"value"="qwert"}
```

Comment: Have you used FIddler or a similar tool to see what is being sent across the wire?

Comment: @DerekVanCuyk thanks. I have added Fiddler request capture to the post.

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked on the UI end, but shouldn'tthe body be in a name-value pair? I.e. value=qwert

Answer (score 0):

Use application/x-www-form-urlencoded as content type when making POST request.

Comment: When I use that content type, I get a 415 Unsupported Media Type response

Comment: From what I can tell your request does not appear to be in x-www-formeurlencoded format. Shouldn't the body be value=qwert.